# Animating an image's perspective using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was any jQuery library that will allow us to change the perspective of an image.

I know that modern browsers already support vendor specific `rotate()` in CSS but it doesn't quite give the desired result. Most of them just vary the width of the image but doesn't shrink the height of one side and increase the height of one side to produce the effect that you are viewing the image from another angle.

Any more details that you may need, please tell me. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I already tried transforms but  they don't increase the height of the side that is moving towards you and decrease the one that is moving away from you. And I don't do full rotations, i just tilt the image a few degrees so the change in height has to really be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 has 2D-transforms and 3D-transforms. While the first is well supported (by all browsers, not by all used versions [[1](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)]) the second is currently only supported by mozilla and webkit [[2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d)]. Both features mostly need vendor-prefixes.

And of course you can animate them with jQuery, if you want to.

Comment: Hi, well I did try transforms. But as I have said, they don't increase the height of the side that is moving towards you and decrease the one that is moving away from you.

Comment: If you use 2D like skew(), then yes. What you want is 3D-transforms.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at script3D.js

http://minimal.be/lab/Sprite3D/

could be usefull for 3D css animations.